# Why is flutter not showing image on Android device

Tags: image, flutter

I have setup image assets like this:

```
/assets/images/img1.png
/assets/images/2.0x/img1.png
/assets/images/3.0x/img1.png
/assets/images/2.0x/img2.png
/assets/images/3.0x/img2.png
```

Then `Image.asset('assets/images/img1.png')` is displayed, but `Image.asset('assets/images/img2.png')` is not.

in pubspec.yaml assets defined like this:

```
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

My question is do I have to add the /assets/images/img2.png ?
If yes, then why? because the device is not 1x resolution. Probably 2x or 3x.

Comment: Can you show us your pubspec.yaml please?

Comment: just updated the question.

Comment: Thanks. When you say img2 is not displayed, you mean `/assets/images/2.0x/img2.png`? Because you don't have an img2.png on your assets folder root..

Comment: You don't have a '/assets/images/img2.png'... you have a '/assets/images/2.0x/img2.png' and '/assets/images/3.0x/img2.png'

Comment: Hardly any devices use 1x... why do I need to define 1x image?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing asset for `/assets/images/img2.png`
Just resize `img2.png` by `50%` and put `img2.png` in `/assets/images/`

Answer (score 0):

Could you please tell us what are you trying to achieve maybe you just need to add one image and using in a boxDecoration in a Container but if you add to you question what exactly want to do, our answer its gonna help you more.

Comment: Updated the question. Thanks